Unable to share stream between two users with PeerJS
I am trying to create something where one user shares their stream and other watches the shared stream. I have created basic sharer and viewer.html files and used PeerJS for connection and video sharing.
The issue i am facing is i am unable to view the stream.
Here is my code
sharer.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Screen - Sharer</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="chat.png" type="image/x-icon">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/peerjs@1.5.4/dist/peerjs.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    * {
      font-family: 'Jetbrains Mono';
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body class="h-screen bg-green-400 flex justify-center items-center">
  <div class="flex gap-2 flex-col bg-white border-2 border-black p-2 justify-center items-center">
    <h1 class="text-xl font-bold">Share Screen</h1>
    <div class="flex justify-center items-center gap-3">
      <p class="text-sm">Your ID: <span id="your-id"></span></p>
      <button id="share" class="p-1 px-2 text-sm border-2 border-black bg-yellow-200">Share</button>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-4">
      <video id="video" class="h-[400px] w-[700px]" autoplay controls></video>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      let stream;
      const btn = document.getElementById('share');
      const video = document.getElementById('video');

      // Initialize PeerJS
      const peer = new Peer('aditya'); // Use a unique ID for this peer

      peer.on('open', id => {
        document.getElementById('your-id').textContent = id;
        console.log('Peer connected with ID:', id);
      });

      btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
          .then(mediaStream => {
            stream = mediaStream;
            video.srcObject = stream;

            // Play the video locally
            video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
              video.play();
            });

            // Wait for a viewer to connect
            peer.on('call', call => {
              console.log('Viewer is calling...');
              call.answer(stream); // Send the stream to the viewer
            });
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.error('Error sharing screen:', err);
          });
      });

      peer.on('error', err => {
        console.error('PeerJS Error:', err);
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>

this is viewer.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Screen - Viewer</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="chat.png" type="image/x-icon">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/peerjs@1.5.4/dist/peerjs.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    * {
      font-family: 'Jetbrains Mono';
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body class="h-screen bg-green-400 flex justify-center items-center">
  <div class="flex gap-2 flex-col bg-white border-2 border-black p-2 justify-center items-center">
    <h1 class="text-xl font-bold">Screen Viewer</h1>
    <div class="flex justify-center items-center gap-3">
      <p class="text-sm">Your ID: <span id="your-id"></span></p>
      <button id="connect" class="p-1 px-2 text-sm border-2 border-black bg-yellow-200">Connect</button>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-4">
      <video id="video" class="h-[400px] w-[700px]" autoplay controls></video>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      const btn = document.getElementById('connect');
      const video = document.getElementById('video');

      // Initialize PeerJS
      const peer = new Peer('agrima'); // Use a unique ID for this peer

      peer.on('open', id => {
        document.getElementById('your-id').textContent = id;
        console.log('Peer connected with ID:', id);
      });

      btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log('Attempting to call "aditya"...');

        // Call the sharer (aditya)
        const call = peer.call('aditya');

        if (call) {
          // Receive the stream
          call.on('stream', remoteStream => {
            console.log('Stream received:', remoteStream);
            video.srcObject = remoteStream;
            video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
              video.play();
            });
          });

          call.on('error', err => {
            console.error('Call error:', err);
          });
        } else {
          console.error('Unable to connect to the sharing peer.');
        }
      });

      peer.on('error', err => {
        console.error('PeerJS Error:', err);
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>

any help is appreciated!
